# Getting content from remote database in TYPO3

Tags: typo3

I wrote web-site and as CMS used TYPO3. Now i have remote database and want to display content from that database on my site. But i dont have any idea, how to do that with typo3. Can someone give me a tipp or advice, where should i to start from. Maybe there is extension for that purpose(typo3 7.6.18).

Comment: Do you want to access a TYPO3 database (with pages and content) on a remote server? Or do you want to get non-TYPO3-related records from a database to show it in TYPO3?

Comment: i want to get non-TYPO3-related records from a database to show it in TYPO3 (from MySQL)

Answer (score 0):

First of all I don't know if there are extensions in TER solving this issue, but I would think that every database has its special behaviour you really need to adjust that extension.

I would prefer to write an own extension and the usage of TYPO3 8 LTS due to the switch to Doctrine DBAL. With that you can handle multiple databases easily.

Docs: https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/CoreApiReference/ApiOverview/Database/Index.html